# RNN for irregular time intervals?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, lstm, recurrent-neural-network, unevenly-spaced-time-series

RNNs are remarkably good for capturing the time-dependence of sequential data. However, what happens when the sequence elements aren't equally spaced in time?

E.g., the first input to the LSTM cell happens on Monday, then no data from Tuesday to Thursday, and then finally new inputs for each of Friday, Saturday, Sunday. One possibility would be to have some kind of NULL vector being fed for Tuesday through Thursday, but that seems to be a silly solution, both because the NULL entries will contaminate the data and because it's a waste of resources.

Any ideas? How do RNNs handle such cases? If there are methods other than RNNs, I welcome those suggestions as well.

Comment: What kind of data is it?  Like can we assume that on some days we get a measurement of some feature that's continuous?  For example, the temperature at some location?

Comment: @user99889 Yes, that could be an example, but I was more thinking of a counter. For example, you get one count at 9:32 am, then nothing, them two counts at 9:37 am, then nothing, etc...

Answer (score 10):

I just wrote a [blog post on that topic](https://www.notion.so/Corrupt-sparse-irregular-and-ugly-Deep-learning-on-time-series-887b823df439417bb8428a3474d939b3)!

In short, I write about different methods for dealing with the problem of sparse / irregular sequential data.

Here is a short outline of methods to try:

- [**Lomb-Scargle** Periodogram](https://www.notion.so/Corrupt-sparse-irregular-and-ugly-Deep-learning-on-time-series-887b823df439417bb8428a3474d939b3#6a427f558ab54ee884324ba0fff50e47)
  This is a way of computing spectrograms on non-equidistant timestep series.
- Data modeling with **[Interpolation networks](https://www.notion.so/Corrupt-sparse-irregular-and-ugly-Deep-learning-on-time-series-887b823df439417bb8428a3474d939b3#856d58ed133a4847ada94bb8f2790def)**
  You really don't want to interpolate naively between timesteps, but training a network to interpolate for you might help!
- **[Neural Ordinary Differential Equation](https://www.notion.so/Corrupt-sparse-irregular-and-ugly-Deep-learning-on-time-series-887b823df439417bb8428a3474d939b3#7754c66cef074827813102ffe3f60f83)** models
  Neural networks that can work with continuous time can naturally work on irregular time series.
- [Add timing ***dt*** to the input](https://www.notion.so/Corrupt-sparse-irregular-and-ugly-Deep-learning-on-time-series-887b823df439417bb8428a3474d939b3#42ecb5b5317747878a063835757cad18) as an additional feature (or positional encoding in Tensorflow)
- Methods for [dealing with missing values](https://www.notion.so/Corrupt-sparse-irregular-and-ugly-Deep-learning-on-time-series-887b823df439417bb8428a3474d939b3#f702f97d712f407eade4981b55b178a5)
  This is only viable if you have vast amounts of data

Hope this helps point you to the right direction :)

Answer (score 4):

If you are feeding in some data vector $v_t$ at time $t$, the straightforward solution is to obtain a one-hot encoding of the day of week, $d_t$, and then simply feed into the network the concatenation of $v_t$ and $d_t$. The time/date encoding scheme can be more complicated if the time format is more complicated than just day of week of course.

Also, depending on exactly how sparse and irregular the data is, NULL entries should be a reasonable solution. I suspect that the input gate of an LSTM would allow the LSTM to properly read off the information of a NULL entry without contaminating the data (the memory/hidden state) as you put it.

Comment: Actually, instead of one-hot encoding, why not just  concatenate a single input node to the LSTM which contains the date, or better yet, the time before the "present", where the present is the last element in the sequence. In this case, those nodes would contain -5 (for Monday), -2 (for Friday), -1 (for Saturday), 0 (for Sunday, i.e., the most recent day). This will circumvent the need for NULLs and at the same time (hopefully) encode by how much the LSTM should "forget" between the recursions. Does this sound reasonable?

Comment: Yes, that should work.

Answer (score 2):

I would try incorporating time interval explicitly into the model. For instance, a conventional time series models such as autoregressive AR(p) can be thought of as discretizations of continuous time model. For instance, AR(1) model:
$$y_t=c+\phi y_{t-1}+\varepsilon_t$$
can be thought of as a version of:
$$y_t=c\Delta t+e^{-\gamma\Delta t}y_{t-\Delta t}+\xi_t\sigma\sqrt {\Delta t}$$

You could draw analogies to time series models from RNN. For instance, $\phi$ in AR(1) process can be seen as a memory weight in RNNs. Hence, you could plug the time difference between observations into your features this way. I must warn that it's just an idea, and I didn't try it myself yet.

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on the data.  For example, if you are processing counts and you just forgot to measure it on some days, then the best strategy is to impute the missing values (e.g., via interpolation or Gaussian processes) and then process the imputed time series with an RNN. By imputing, you would be embedding knowledge.

If the missingness is meaningful (it was too hot too measure counts on some days), then it's best to impute perhaps and also append an indicator vector that is 1 if the value was missing and 0 otherwise.

Comment: The absence of data can't be dealt with by imputation since data is objectively absent in this case, not simply the result of a missed measurement. As for the addition of label for the missing values (e.g., 0 or 1 as you suggested), that would be tantamount to a null value. The problem with that is the sparsity of the data: The sliding windows that the RNN is trained on will mostly contain nulls, whereas, in practice, one would like to cram in as much information while at the same time, accounting for the fact that they are interspersed in time.